# Spring boot OpenSessionInViewFilter with actuator and custom Security

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot to create RESTful web service. For security I am using a BasicAuthenticationFilter and a custom AuthenticationProvider by extending the AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider. I'm using method level security with the @Secured annotation in my controller class. It all works fine except I am trying to get spring-actuator working as well.

The problem with actuator is that I am getting a hibernate exception when trying to authenticate the request because no session is open. So when I go to http://localhost:8081/info I get a hibernate exception.

It seems as though actuator is using a separate filter chain from the rest of the app. If that's the case, I'm sure there is a good reason for it. However, I don't know how to register my OpenSessionInViewFilter so that it is the first filter in each of my filter chains. My OpenSessionInViewFilter is registered via a FilterRegistrationBean in one of my @Configuration classes.

Spring boot is great but there is a lot of magic going on under the hood and I haven't yet figured out how to dig into their code and see where it all starts and follow it through.

Here is some of my configuration. I tried to include what I think is important. Please let me know if there is another piece that you would like to see.

Any help is appreciated.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().authenticationDetailsSource(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource()
            {
                @Override
                public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context)
                {
                    return new ThirdPartyAuthenticationDetails(context);
                }
            })
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
} 

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("thirdPartySystemDAO")
    private EntityDAO<ThirdPartySystem> thirdPartySystemDAO;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider result = new ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider();
        result.setSecurityService(thirdPartySecurityService());
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThirdPartySecurityService thirdPartySecurityService()
    {
        ThirdPartySecurityServiceImpl result = new ThirdPartySecurityServiceImpl();
        result.setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
        result.setThirdPartySystemDAO(thirdPartySystemDAO);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Here is the stack trace when trying to access the /info endpoint of actuator.**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134) ~[spring-orm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at com.redi.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.getCurrentSession(HibernateDAO.java:495) ~[redi-dao-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.redi.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.createQuery(HibernateDAO.java:460) ~[redi-dao-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.redi.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.findOneWhere(HibernateDAO.java:58) ~[redi-dao-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.mycompany.DefaultVerifiService.getInstitution(DefaultVerifiService.java:349) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.thirdparty.ws.security.ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ThirdPartyAuthenticationProvider.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:168) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

Answer (score 1):

Register OpenSessionInViewFilter putting the following code on your configuration class:

```
    @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilterBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter filter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.setOrder(5);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

You must remember... if you are using Hibernate, declare OpenSessionInViewFilter. But if you are using JPA, declare OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I solved this already. Can't remember how since this was over a year ago.

Comment: Hi, why bean has "5" in order?